# Slick 3.0.0 - How to sortBy on a query with joinLeft

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0, play-slick

This question is related to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190955/slick-dynamic-sortby-in-a-query-with-left-join/24191448#24191448?newreg=fc94bcd17d3f410bb5f563d3c4a7eede). I'm also trying to sort on a query with a joinLeft but in slick 3.0.0. And as the Option Rep are automatically lifted how would I do the exact same thing ?:

```
def list(filter: String, orderBy: Int):Future[Seq[(Computer, Option[Company])]] = {
    val initialQuery = for {
        (computer, company) <- Computer.filter(_.name like filter) leftJoin 
            Company on (_.companyId === _.id)
    } yield (computer, company)

    val sortedQuery = orderBy match {
        case 2 => initialQuery.sortBy(_._1.name) //Works ok, column from a primary table
        case 3 => initialQuery.sortBy(_._2.map(_.name)) //could not find implicit value for parameter ol: slick.lifted.OptionLift[slick.lifted.ColumnOrdered[String],slick.lifted.Rep[Option[QO]]]
    }
    db.run(sortedQuery.result)
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that missing parenthesis is just a typo. I had this problem recently when I was specifying the sort direction in the wrong place, using your example:

```
case 3 => initialQuery.sortBy(_._2.map(_.name.asc))
```

It should be:

```
case 3 => initialQuery.sortBy(_._2.map(_.name).asc)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but yes it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I had a joinLeft and I want to order on a boolean column. You must be decide when Its join is empty what value you want replace it.

for example:

```
initialQuery.sortBy(_._2.map(_.name).getOrElse(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you copied the correct code?

```
case 3 => data.sortBy(_._2.map(_.name) //could not find implicit value for parameter
```

Missing a ")"

Should be

```
case 3 => data.sortBy(_._2.map(_.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the fields into the result set.
For example:

```
 val initialQuery = for {
        (computer, company) <- Computer.filter(_.name like filter) leftJoin Company on (_.companyId === _.id)
        } yield (computer, company, company.map(_.name))

    val sortedQuery =  orderBy match {
        case 2 => initialQuery.sortBy(_._1.name) 
        case 3 => initialQuery.sortBy(_._3)
    }

    db.run(sortedQuery.map(v => (v._1, v._2).result)
```